# function doesn't do anything even though it has been called

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I called a function here

```
function gameLoop(){

 xpos = Math.min(Math.max(xpos + xspeed,minx),maxx);
 ypos = Math.min(Math.max(ypos + yspeed,miny),maxy);

 gaurd();

 document.getElementById('character').style.left = xpos;
 document.getElementById('character').style.top = ypos;

 if (upPressed == 1)
   yspeed = Math.max(yspeed - 1,-1*maxSpeed);
 if (downPressed == 1)
   yspeed = Math.min(yspeed + 1,1*maxSpeed)
 if (rightPressed == 1)
   xspeed = Math.min(xspeed + 1,1*maxSpeed);
 if (leftPressed == 1)
   xspeed = Math.max(xspeed - 1,-1*maxSpeed);

 if (upPressed == 0 && downPressed == 0)
   slowDownY();
 if (leftPressed == 0 && rightPressed == 0)
   slowDownX();

 setTimeout("gameLoop()",10);

}
```

It is the gaurd() bit but when i run the code it doesn't call it.

gaurd is

```
function gaurd() {


alert("getPricing just got called");
$( "#gaurd" ).hide;
$( "#gaurd1" ).hide;
$( "#gaurd2" ).hide;
var gaurdPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

if  (gaurdPos = 1 ) 
    $( "#gaurd" ).show;


if  (gaurdPos = 2) 
    $( "#gaurd1" ).show;


if  (gaurdPos = 3) 
    $( "#gaurd2" ).show;

}
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't call?

I am a complete idiot thank you ballabin for suggesting that. I had written a gaurd function somewhere else and didn't delete it when i moved it.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: There is no errors and i am not sure what you mean Nano.

Comment: @user3716513 `.hide` and `.show` are methods not properties do `.show()` and `.hide()`

Comment: I have an alert in gaurd() and it doesn't show it and i already tried console.log. also kyle thanks for that but the function doesn't call.

Comment: gaurd - "A cloak-like garment which was usually worn by Early-Christian Priestly Writers."  (urban dictionary).  I do not think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: for debugging try commenting out the first 2 lines of code before your call to `gaurd()` and see if it still doesn't get called.

Comment: Yes i know i spelt it wrong.

Comment: @user3716513 - BTW, maybe this `setTimeout("gameLoop()",10);` works because JS is quite forgiving, but it really should be `setTimeout(gameLoop,10);`

Comment: it still doesn't call ballbin.

Comment: Are you sure that all of your js is being added to the page?  You wouldn't happen to have a different `gaurd()` being pulled in from somewhere else?  It is strange that it's not being called but yet you're not seeing js errors in your console...

Comment: @user3716513 - to be sure, put an `alert('calling gaurd');` in `gameLoop()` just before the call to gaurd, do you see that alert?

Comment: *"I had written a gaurd function somewhere else and didn't delete it when i moved it."* OK, can we close the question then?

Comment: @user3716513 - AND, I recomment replacing your `alert();` with `console.log();`. (And then press F12 and open the console tab in the Dev Tools of your browser to see the output, I find Chrome works best for this)

Comment: FYI, if you had tried to isolate the problem and create a reproducible  example, you'd have probably find the source of the problem yourself. There is a reason why we expect *complete* examples, most of the time people are able to fix the problem themselves during that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gameLoop() starts by referencing a bunch of undefined variables:

```
xpos = Math.min(Math.max(xpos + xspeed,minx),maxx);
ypos = Math.min(Math.max(ypos + yspeed,miny),maxy);
```

Namely xpos, xspeed, minx, maxx, ypos, yspeed, miny, maxy.

Comment: They are defined i just only showed the relevant bits.

Comment: @user3716513: How then should we distinguish between the real problem and problems you introduced by posting? The code you post should be **complete**: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The variables required by the functions are relevant. You should create a jsfiddle showing a scenario where your code breaks when you believe it shouldn't.

Comment: Everything works the way i want it to except it doesn't call the gaurd function.

Comment: @user3716513: In the case there must be an error before the `gaurd();` line which prevents further execution. And the only problem that is in the code you posted is that `xpos`, `xspeed`, `minx` and `maxx` (same for `*y`) are not defined. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Comment: if i comment those lines out it still doesn't call it.

Comment: @user3716513: Then `gameLoop` is not called.

Comment: nothing would work if gameLoop wasn't called but it does work.

Comment: @user3716513: Then either `guard` is not in the scope of `gameLoop` or `gaurd` is called but it doesn't do what you want it to do. Again, [learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). Since you are not providing a proper description of your problem, or an example that reproducing the problem, all we can do is guess (which doesn't really help you and is annoying for us).

Comment: @user3716513 Stick a `debugger` statement as the first argument in gameloop and check it gets called and with the vars defined as you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're not executing your functions with `()`.

Change

```
foo.show
```

to

```
foo.show()
```

and see if it works. Same for `hide`.

Comment: The function doesn't call but you are right, thank you.